# Where can I find video of FDR's speech, similar to fireside chat #5?

Tags: president, fdr

I am trying to find a speech given by FDR that is almost identical, in parts, to his June 28, 1934 *[fireside chat](https://millercenter.org/the-presidency/presidential-speeches/june-28-1934-fireside-chat-5-addressing-critics)*.

Transcript:

> I feel timid people, who fair progress will try to give you new and strange names by what we are doing. Sometimes they will call it Communist and sometime socialism. I believe that what we are doing today is a fulfilment of old and tested American ideas.

It is very similar to his June 28th chat but not identical. The video quality in the clip is of far better quality than the fireside chat.

Comment: Is it possible that "fair" is a typo for "fear"?  How accurate is this transcription? (and to avoid plagiarism, what is the source of this transcription?)  I can find no record of this quote anywhere other than the referenced fireside chat,.  Although youtube lists this as [fireside chat #4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPnFh39YI-U&ab_channel=jcm)

Comment: @MCW - The text identifies that as from a transcript. Yes, I suspect whoever created that transcript (post author or someone up the line) didn't do the best of jobs (perhaps hindered by poor broadcast or recording quality).

Comment: Or by Roosevelt's accent...

Comment: https://video.alexanderstreet.com/watch/dirt-and-deeds-in-mississippi/transcript?context=channel:civil-rights-workers-killed-neshoba-county-ms-june-6-1964       This is a link to the documentary (the FDR speech is at 29:05).  It is very similar to his fireside chat but obviously taken from a different video.   Sorry about the fair/fear typo, thank you everyone.